# How to count unique clusters for a value

Tags: sql

Assuming we have the following table:

```
ID   Activity   PersonID
1      C1          P1
2      C2          P1
3      C3          P1
4      C11         P2
5      C1          P2
6      C1          P3
6      C11         P3
...
100    C2          P50
```

where each person's activities are recorded by activity code, I'd like to be able to have the number of unique groups of activities for each person that exit in this table. We know that there are certain bundles of activities that are repeated for different PersonIDs in this table. I'd like to know how many different unique groupings there are and what those groupings are. 
For example, P2 and P3 both have the same activities, and this would make this a unique group of activities.

Is there an SQL query that can give me this?

Comment: Please show us that you have at least attempted to solve the problem.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And what is the expected output based on your sample data?

Comment: I have tried, to no avail. I'm now thinking I should write Python code to solve the problem.
I am using MS-Access
Based on the sample data, I'd like to see the following output:
GroupID  Frequency  Activity

1--------------10------------C1

1-------------10------------C2

1--------------10------------C3

2--------------14------------C1

2--------------14------------C11

Answer (score 0):

If the database that you are using supports aggregate string concatenation, then that is an easy way to solve your problem.  For instance, using MySQL's `group_concat()`:

```
select activities, group_concat(personid) as persons
from (select personid, group_concat(activity order by activity) as activities
      from t
      group by personid
     ) p
group by activities;
```